# Touch screen stops responding, but only on rails collection_select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, touch

I have a `collection_select` in my rails view that displays a list of cars from the database. The web app is displayed (using Chrome) on a laptop that is connected to an Acer touch-screen monitor, which works well. I am having a problem where the cars `collection_select` field in my form will stop responding to the touch screen. I have done a ton of trouble-shooting, but I can't seem to isolate the issue.

- The `collection_select` menu opens, but it will not scroll and you cannot select a car from the touch-screen monitor
- The rest of the same browser page still responds to the touch screen
- The `collection_select` works if you use the laptop's trackpad
- Closing and re-opening the browser fixes the problem (until it randomly happens again)
- Turning the touch-screen off and back on does not fix the problem

Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?

The app is using Rails 4.2, Bootstrap 3 and simple_form.

Comment: Have you tried on any touch phone?

Comment: No, but this dashboard is displayed on a large touch-screen monitor that we provide to the client and is not intended to be used on a smaller screen.

Comment: I don't think that the rails backend is directly responsible for your error. It's sounds like it is related to some javascript or css stuff. You should try different test scenarios in order to localize the error: Try to copy the generated html to a static html file. Remove javascript references one by one and test again. If you can't locate the problem, try to remove every stylesheet reference one by one and test again.